# Spinner and value

Tags: android, toast

I populate my spinner and I want a toast.show when the value of the spinner are right. 
For example:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
if (catspinner.equals("England")&&(planspinner1.equals("London"))){
Toast.makeText(ActivityIta.this, "Capital is London", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
else Toast.makeText(ActivityIta.this, "No capital", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();}
});
```

My result is only, "No capital". Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using winforms? If so which version? The spinner is not available to me (as far as I can see - It must be an old control now as the Numeric UpDown is favoured more) but it looks like the evaluation of your if statement is simply failing.

Just to rule it out, (and because I can't check for myself) is there a catspinner.value or catspinner.text property that you could evaluate against rather than the control itself?

Also have you debugged and checked the values being returned by catspinner at the point of evaluation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using android